# Copy package/class returns: package dk.prod does not exist

Tags: java

In a file the following class is imported

```
import dk.sample.VirksomhedKalenderHentClient;
```

I want to create a copy of `VirksomhedKalenderHentClient` because I want to try to make some changes without changing the original class and place it in `prod` instead of `sample` like this

```
import dk.prod.VirksomhedKalenderHentClient;
```

1. Create a new directory: `dk/prod`
2. Copy `dk/sample/VirksomhedKalenderHentClient.java` to `dk/prod`
3. Change package in the copied file `package dk.prod`
4. Change import to: `import dk.prod.VirksomhedKalenderHentClient`
5. Compile

But when copiling this error is returned

```
[ERROR] /.../dk/sample/mvc/ServiceTestAction.java:[9,28] package dk.prod does not exist
[ERROR] /.../dk/sample/mvc/ServiceTestAction.java:[98,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class VirksomhedKalenderHentClient
```